# Installer for Subversion: CollabNetSubversionEdge-5.2.4_linux-x86_64.tar.gz

Tags: linux, installation, svn, collabnet, subversion-edge

Does anyone have the installer file for version: 5.2.4 - CollabNetSubversionEdge-5.2.4_linux-x86_64.tar.gz
OR knows who to get it ?

The link "http://www.collab.net/svnedge" on the official website :http://help.collab.net/index.jsp?topic=/csvn/action/installcsvnonwindows.html seems to be routing to another website "https://integrations.digital.ai/"

tried searching on google and did not find any link to any installer files